# Perl: Can not print occurence of string "." from an array

Tags: arrays, string, perl, find-occurrences

i have an array which contain (head , b , v , . , b, v, end).
i try to find and get the ".", and do sth after that (example: print out ).

for unknown reason i can't get the "."

so i did a simple code to count occurence of char inside the array.
here's the code:

```
$stylefile="log2.style";
open ("styles", $stylefile) or die ("can't open file");

while (<styles>)
{
$temp = $_;
chomp($temp);
push @style,$temp;
}    
print @style;
# here is the array "headbv.bvend"

@bar = grep(/v/i, @style);
print @bar;
# it prints out vv

@fullstop = grep(/./i, @style);
# it prints out the entire array values.
```

any clue how to get occurences of "." ?

Answer (score 6):

Use `/[.]/` instead of `/./` to match a full stop.

[man perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You also could use `/\./` to match a full stop.

Test program:

```
$ perl -e ' $_ = "a.b.c"; @f = m/(\.)/g; print "@f\n" '
. .
```

Answer (score 1):

The dot is a special character in regular expressions. It matches any character - which explains the behaviour you are seeing.

To make a special character just match itself you need to escape it with a backslash.

```
@fullstop = grep(/\./i, @style);
```

You should probably read the [Perl regular expression tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) (or [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html))